# PHP mysql_fetch does not return values

Tags: php, mysql

Being quite new with PHP, I cannot find any solution why this does not work. The query is OK and the resource is returned. But I dunno why fetch_assoc does not print values. Thanks

```
$query=sprintf("SELECT ID,NAME FROM USERS WHERE PASS='%s' AND NAME='%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($p),mysql_real_escape_string($n));

$result=mysql_query($query);

if ($result)
 {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['ID'];
    echo $row['NAME'];
}
}

}
```

Comment: try to get an error message if you don't have one at this time. You can do this in following way: `$result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());`.

This will print you an error, witch helps you (or us) to solve your problem ;)

Comment: `mysql_num_rows($result)` may be returning 0 so there's nothing to fetch. Have you tested with dummy data whereby MySQL will definitely return results?

Answer (score 2):

Some simple questions to start with:

- Have you done a [var_dump](http://it.php.net/var-dump)($row) to see what it returns?
- Are you sure that the name and the password you specify are actually in the database?
- Have you encrypted the password in the database (and not in the query)?
- Have you a valid database connection ? (I know the answer is yes but a double check won't harm anyone and maybe save some headache)

Edit:

- Added a link to the man page for var_dump.
- As already suggested use [mysql_error()](http://it.php.net/mysql-error) to find what goes wrong. (A simple echo mysql_error(); after $result=mysql_query($query); will suffice)
- write <strike>down</strike> out the query to see if something goes wrong with the escaping.

Comment: Connection is OK. No encryption done and I can see the values in the database. I am pretty new to PHP so I dont know about var_dump.

Comment: @Petr, http://php.net/functionName will get you the documentation for any function, for example http://php.net/var_dump will get you docs for var_dump()

Answer (score 0):

1.Echo out Your $query to see if it is what You like to be for debugging purposes;
2. Check $row['ID'] AND ['NAME'] if they are really UPPER letters;
3. Use mysql error reporting after if ($result){....} else { echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n"; }  where $link is Your DB handle.

Comment: 2. Yes, they are. In the query they are reported uppercase and php maintains the case used in the query, not the case used in the table definition

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that rows were returned? You can use `mysql_num_rows($result)` to get the count. The only thing I can think of looking at your code is that you're passing in the password in plain text and the version in the DB is MD5 or something.

Comment: This is where I would start if you aren't getting any errors and it's simply not returning any values (or something like "Resource #100"). The $result variable will be defined even if a row isn't replaced.

Try inserting echo(mysql_num_rows($result)); after $result=mysql_query($query);. If it prints "0", something's wrong with your query. If it returns "1", echo a dummy sting inside your while control to see if it prints anything.